# Applet using JNA called by Javascript = Access Denied

Tags: java, javascript, security, exception, applet

I coded an Applet where I communicate with a device using JNA. I need to get a value readed by the device and save it in the database. The solution that I proposed to myself is to call an Applet method via javascript and inject the return in the JSP. Well... during the execution of the Applet, I need to download a DLL file (p.s. running on Windows), save it on disk and add the path where it was downloaded to the JNA path. But, when I run the Applet, it throws a java.security.AccessControlException, saying "access denied". Here's the JSP code...

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>..:: Testing ::..</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myTrigger').click(function() {
                    alert($('#myApplet')[0].capture());                    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Applet</h1>
        <object type="application/x-java-applet" height="0" width="0" id="myApplet">
            <param name="code" value="AppletHW" />
            <param name="archive" value="AppletHW.jar,jna.jar" />
        </object>
        <a id="myTrigger" href="#">Click here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and my Applet looks like this...

```
public class AppletHW extends Applet {

    public String capture() {        
        String folder = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        File path = new File(folder + File.separator + ".applethw");
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", path.getAbsolutePath());[/code]

        // I download the DLL file

        MyDLL lib = (MyDLL) Native.loadLibrary("MyDLL", MyDLL.class);
        return lib.capture();
    }
}
```

P.S. Both my applet jar and JNA are signed.

Comment: Does the current windows user have admin permissions? If no, try to launch your code when user has admin permissions.

Comment: I think that the SecurityManager for applets forbids loading DLLs as they can contain malicious code. Probably you can modify the local security policy (via policytool) so that the applet can override this restrictions.
See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/applets/

Comment: Search the **Related**  threads for `doPrivileged`.  (Then read them, understand what it means, implement it, test it.. If all that fails, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.)

Comment: Well, I've read a lot last days, and someone in a forum said that when you call a Applet method by Javascript, the valid permissions are the permissions of Javascript. This way, as Javascript can't access local files and folders, the applet can't too. So, I've solved this situation creating a Ajax script that only inject the Applet in the page when I click in the <a> element. So, the applet calls itself the functions. To inject the applet result back in JSP, I've called javascript inside the applet. E.g: getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:setMyContent(\"" + content + "\")"));